# SQL: check if a value exitst in a group, if true, only return the true

Tags: sql-server

Assume I have the following table

ExampleTable

```
id ¦ value
--------------
1  ¦ True
1  ¦ False
2  ¦ False
3  ¦ True
3  ¦ False
```

I know that there will be a False in all ids, but the output I want is that if there is a True then just give me the True row. Basically;

```
id ¦ value
--------------
1  ¦ True
2  ¦ False
3  ¦ True
```

How can I do this?

I have tried:

```
select 
    *
from 
    ExampleTable
group by 
    id
having 
    max(case value when 'True' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

But this either deletees all Falses or all Trues.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * 
from TestDb 
where value=1 
union 
select * 
from testDb 
where value=0 
     and id not in
          (select id from TestDb where value=1)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: I understand this logic, basically I am selecting the Trues joining the Falses which id has not been selected yet. I wonder if there is a more efficient method of achieving this same logic as its the one that works best for me.

Answer (score 5):

Since  `'True'` is alphabetically greater than `'False'` you can just do

```
select id, max(value) as value
from ExampleTable
group by id
```

But you actually should store TRUE/FALSE values as  `bit` instead of a text data type.

Comment: Probably worth giving him a `BIT` of a nudge about datatypes while you're helping him in case he's actually storing it as text :-)

Comment: Your answer helped!, but I had to add some code as with a as (select * from ExampleTable) select select id, max(value) as value from a group by id. Because my code was actually somewhat more complex than the example I wrote. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In complicated query,

```
Select  * from
(
 select *,Row_Number(partition by by id order by value desc)rn from ExampleTable

)tbl
where rn=1
```

Another query,

```
Select top 1 * from
(
select *,1 Priority from ExampleTable
where value='True'

union all

select *,2 Priority from ExampleTable
where value='False'
)tbl
order by  Priority
```